# I need to sort data on the back-end level using @RequestParam in native query Jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, sorting, jpa

So, idea is simple, I need to have an back-end sorting and filtering URL, smth like that:

```
/users?find=Paul&sortBy=name:asc
```

So far I have this controller method:

```
@GetMapping("/users")
    public List<User> findUserByName(@RequestParam Optional<String> find,
                                     @RequestParam Optional<Integer> page,
                                     @RequestParam Optional<String> sort)
    {
        return userRepository.findByName(find.orElse("_"),
                new PageRequest(page.orElse(0),5,
                        Sort.Direction.ASC, sort.orElse("name")));
    }
```

And this UserRepository that extends JpaRepository:

```
@Query("select u from User u where name like %?1%")
    List<User> findByName(String name, Pageable pageable);
```

My question is: I am specifying the sort status (Ascending/Descending) in the Controller itself, but I want it to be specified in url, like here:

```
/users?find=Paul&sortBy=name:asc
```

but for now it works for me only like that

```
/users?find=Paul&sortBy=name
```

and it gets sorted in ascending order automatically, because I specified it in the Controller method.

Could You be so kind to explain me how can I do that, please :)?

Take care!

Comment: Probably you need to add conditional statements to check for the sort parameter. If it is `:desc` then sort it in descending otherwise in ascending order.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the reply, but my question is - how can I do it with Optional parameter.

Comment: Clean solution would be to add another query param, something like "sortOrder" and check for it in the backend, if it's null, do whatever you want to do, otherwise sort in ascending or descending order depending on it's value.

Comment: Thank you for the clean and understandable response :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `Direction.fromString(order)` method where order  can be "asc" 
or "desc"

for order you should keep seperate param

```
@RequestParam Optional<String> order


userRepository.findByName(find.orElse("_"),
                new PageRequest(page.orElse(0),5,
                        Sort.Direction.fromString(order), sort.orElse("name")));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add another `optional` request parameter to your controller (also it should be optional by setting required=false). In this way:

```
public enum SortType {
    Dsc, Asc;
}

@GetMapping("/test/url")
public void handle(@RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "Asc") Optional<SortType> sort) {

    switch (sort.get()) {
        case Dsc:{/*sort descending*/}
        default:{/*sort ascending*/}
    }
}
```

In addition, 'sort' parameter can be used for calling repository methods canoditionally.